# return success : ok and api 'unfortunately stopped' in device(push notification)

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am new to api programming. I have developed an api and at the end I just want to add a notification functionality.The App is running successfully before push notification is installed. After installing the push notification plugin, it returns 'Success : OK' while the my api stopped with

> 'Unfortunately app has been stopped'.

How can I get my reg ID from GCM?
I have installed this push notification plugin:

```
com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin
com.parse.cordova.core.pushplugin
```

Here is my code:

```
     var pushNotification;
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


    function onDeviceReady()
    {

            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');

    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e)
            {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>backbutton event received</li>');

        if( $("#home").length > 0)
    {
                // call this to get a new token each time. don't call it to reuse existing token.
                //pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
                e.preventDefault();
                navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
    else
    {
                navigator.app.backHistory();
    }
    }, false);

    try 
    { 
                pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering ' + device.platform + '</li>');
                if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' || device.platform == 'amazon-fireos' )
                {
        pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"818908559402","ecb":"onNotification"});        // required!
        }
                else
                {
                    pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});    // required!
                }
            }
    catch(err) 
    { 
                txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n"; 
                txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n"; 
                alert(txt); 
    } 
    }




    // handle APNS notifications for iOS
    onNotificationAPN = function (e)
    {
        if (e.alert) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>push-notification: ' + e.alert + '</li>');
            // showing an alert also requires the org.apache.cordova.dialogs plugin
            navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
        }

        if (e.sound) {
            // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
            var snd = new Media(e.sound);
            snd.play();
        }

        if (e.badge) {
            pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
        }
    }


    // handle GCM notifications for Android
    onNotification = function (e)
    {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

        switch( e.event )
        {
            case 'registered':
    if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
    {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
    }
            break;

            case 'message':
                // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
                // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
                if (e.foreground)
                {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');

        // on Android soundname is outside the payload. 
        // On Amazon FireOS all custom attributes are contained within payload
        var soundfile = e.soundname || e.payload.sound;
        // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
        // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
        var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+ soundfile);

        my_media.play();
        }
                else
                {   // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
        if (e.coldstart)
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
        else
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                }

                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
                //android only
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
                //amazon-fireos only
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> TIMESTAMP: ' + e.payload.timeStamp + '</li>');
                break;

            case 'error':
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
                break;

            default:
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
                break;
        }
    }

    function tokenHandler (result) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
        // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
        // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
    }

    function successHandler (result) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
    }

    function errorHandler (error) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>errorHandler:'+ error +'</li>');
    }

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project goto properties -> Java Build Path. Choose Order export tab. Make sure that Android Private Libraries is selected. also select android-support-v4.jar

Hope It works fine :)